# Ansible - Conditionally set volume and tls hostname based on inventory file in docker module

Tags: docker, ansible, boot2docker

I'm using Ansible to deploy my containers to production. During development, I'd like to have Ansible deploy all containers on my localhost instead of the production servers.

Production servers run on Ubuntu, localhost is OS X with boot2docker.

I have 2 inventory files, production and localhost. My dir structure looks like this:

```
.
|--inventories
|  |localhost
|  |production
|
|--group_vars
|  |all
|  |localhost
|  |production
|
|--roles
|  |--web
|     |--tasks
         |main.yml
|
|web.yml
```

*web.yml* just defines the host group and assigns the `web` role.

*/roles/web/tasks/main.yml* looks like this:

```
- name: Run web container
  docker:
    name: web
    image: some/image
    state: reloaded
    ...
    tls_hostname: boot2docker
    volumes:
      - "/data/db:/data/db"
    env:
      ...
  tags:
    - ...
```

I need to set `tls_hostname` conditionally, only if the localhost inventory was used; likewise, I want to set the volume only if the production inventory file was used.

Very new to Ansible - it seems like I'm not approaching this to right way there's an easier way to do this? I want to avoid creating completely separate tasks to deploy locally; I just need a way to define volume and `tls_hostname` conditionally (and leave it at default setting otherwise)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of Ansible 1.8, you can omit variables and module parameters using the default filter with the special [`omit`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_filters.html#omitting-parameters) value. For example,

```
- name: Run web container
  docker:
    name: web
    image: some/image
    state: reloaded
    ...
    tls_hostname: "{{ hostname | default('some default value') }}"
    volumes: "{{ volumes | default(omit) }}"
    env:
      ...
  tags:
    - ...
```

Comment: Get very similar questions a lot.  Would be nice if you linked to the documentation on this and similar issues.

Answer (score 2):

I see you do have `group_vars` files for `localhost` and `production`. Are you familiar with that [concept](http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_best_practices.html#group-and-host-variables)? Because I think this is what you're looking for.

The variables defined in the `group_vars` section will be applied if the host belongs to the respective group.

> I need to set `tls_hostname` conditionally, only if the localhost inventory was used; likewise, I want to set the volume only if the production inventory file was used.

So that sounds like you want to define `tls_hostname` in `./group_vars/localhost` and `volume` in `./group_vars/production`.

> (and leave it at default setting otherwise)

Default values can be stored in several places. If you have a role you can store in `<role>/defaults/main.yml`. `group_vars/all` also is possible. As well you can set a default value in your yml's.

```
- name: Run web container
  docker:
    name: web
    image: some/image
    state: reloaded
    ...
    tls_hostname: "{{ hostname | default('some default value') }}"
    volumes: "{{ volumes | default(['/data/db:/data/db']) }}"
    env:
      ...
  tags:
    - ...
```

If `hostname` or `volumes` are not defined Ansible will fall back to the defined default value.

Comment: Your solution works for tls_hostname as it has a default value, but not for volumes. In one scenario there *is* a volume and in the other scenario there is *no* volume set.

Ansible throws an error when volume is specified with no/null value.

Comment: Did you try an empty set as default? `default([])`

Comment: Or simply `no` or `false`.

Comment: tried that - the volume requires a value; null throws an error.